# Sigma-finiteness and absolutely continuous measures

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

Suppose we have an abstract $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and let $\nu$ be another measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ as well, with the property that $\nu \ll\mu$,  i.e $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$ .

Does it necessarily imply that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $(X,\mathscr{A})$?

I thought of using the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, but then realized that the theorem goes under the assumptions that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite to begin with.

I also tried to prove it by contradiction, but the usual tricks that I am aware of does not work very good on infinite measures.

Maybe there is a nice counter-example to my claim?

Comment: For Radon-Nikodym Theorem, it's enough for $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite; $\nu$ doesn't have to. See, e.g., Theorem 5.11 of Erhan Çınlar's "Probability and Stochastics". Note further that the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ cannot be removed in general. See Exercise 5.19 of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any uncountable set, $\mathscr A$ the sigma-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets, and $\mu$, $\nu \colon \mathscr A \to [0,\infty]$ given by 
$$ \mu(A) = \begin{cases} 0 & A \text{ is countable}\\
                          1 & A \text{ is uncountable}
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$ \nu(A) = \begin{cases} 0 & A \text{ is countable}\\
                          \infty & A \text{ is uncountable}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\mu$ is finite, $\nu \ll \mu$, but $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler counterexample: Let $X=\{0\}$. Define $\mu$ and $\nu$ by $\mu(X)=1$, $\nu(X)=\infty$.